# sencha rest store json responses

Tags: php, json, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I just got stuck developing a restful store for sencha. As far as I see my problem is what i return wrong structured responses. Is there any documentation out there showing the structure my json response should have for sencha extjs for the different requests e.g.:

- index > get all contents / no rights, error message
- get > id available / doesn't exist / no rights to access
- post > successful / not ...
- delet > successful / not ...

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

There's an excellent documentation regarding [**RESTful Web Services with Sencha Touch**](http://www.sencha.com/learn/legacy/Manual%3aRESTful_Web_Services#HTTP_Methods).

Worth reading it. Hope it helps you out!

Comment: I pretty much know this already. As I understand it I should answer every request with status 200 ok and use the "success":true/false property to tell extjs if the request was successful. But how to I notify the client e.g. if an asset is not allowed for a specific user? or how do i answer the index (get all assets) correctly?